# Serialize to JSON a class that hides member of base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, json-serialization

There are two classes:

```
class Document {
    public DocumentItem[] DocumentItemList { get; set; }
}

class DocumentViewModel : Document{
    public new DocumentItemViewModel[] DocumentItemList { get; set; }
}
```

`DocumentItemList` in derived class hides `DocumentItemList` in base class.

When `DocumentViewModel` object is serialized to JSON:

```
DocumentViewModel instance = CreateObject(); // object gets created
string serializedContent = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(instance);
```

there are two DocumentItemLists in serialized string:

```
{
    "DocumentItemList": [{
            ... etc. ...
    }],
    "DocumentItemList": null
}
```

**Why is it like that? This causes error, when data is deserialized.**

(BTW, I tested serialization with Newtonsoft.JSON, and that serializer doesn't have this error).

Comment: Even Microsoft is using Json.NET in several projects/libraries. Forget JavaScriptSerializer and use Json.NET

Comment: @meJustAndrew, you're right, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to stick with `JavaScriptSerializer`, you may consider to use `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, on the property you want to be ignored, this is discussed about the shadowed properties in a thread [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/463).

Here you go:

```
class Document {
    public DocumentItem[] DocumentItemList { get; set; }
}

class DocumentViewModel : Document{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public new DocumentItemViewModel[] DocumentItemList { get; set; }
}
```